# Php session files have different owners

Tags: php, apache, session, apache-config

i have a problem with my session files...

if i go to my site directly (www.example.com) then php session files owner is www-data:www-data but if i go do the site via www.example.com/index.php then the owner of the session files is ftp:www-data and the resulting problem is when i want to start the session but the session file allready exists but having a different owner php can not open the session file for writing.

i'm running apache + php5

Comment: Sounds like an apache config issue. I would add an apache tag.

Comment: @Kevin, nice call added apache tag for him ;)

Comment: the problem is that i can not find any problems with my apache config file... and that is the real problem :)

Comment: Agreed, please post some of your apache config, namely the virtualhost sections and the User / Group directives.

Comment: i'm using mod_php
@Josh - could you point me where to find that info? and also i'm using default settings for apache (at least i beleave they are default settings)

Comment: and here you can find my config of virtualhost http://pastebin.com/f35720146

Comment: @Gabriel: User / Group directives would be in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf... Is this the only VirtualHost you have? I am very confused as to what's going on here...

Comment: @Gabriel please edit original post (so it's easy for newcomers to find) with:
contents of httpd.conf
contents of index.php
contents of .htaccess if there is one
output of ps -aux if you can run it on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with who the owner of index.php was and all php files. All php files should have had the owner www-data:www-data... but a small fraction of files was uploaded via ftp and so the owner was ftp:www-data.

And the session file had the same owner as the php file where the session was started... don't know if this is spessific only to my server.

Answer (score 0):

By chance are there two (instances) servers running on port 80?  I don't know how else to explain the difference in ownership (unless your script is somehow explicitly changing the ownership).

I suggest removing all session data, and watching them get created one by one.  Try it with additional files as well.  If they ping-pong (one by ftp, one by www-data, one by ftp, one by www-data, ...) then I would lean toward two servers running.

You're not by chance behind a load balancer are you?

Comment: The permissions of any file you write should match the permission of the session files.  Just an FYI to help in your debugging.

Comment: i have found the solution for this problem... i will post it soon, but this was not the correct answer...
and i'm not behind a load balancer :)

Comment: I'm anxious to hear what the root problem was.